# scp of a file is sucessful, but scp of the folder fails

Tags: scp

When I use scp to copy one file to my local machine, it is successful:

```
scp -r administrator@10.6.120.80:/NMM/sector0.txt ./
administrator@10.6.120.80's password:
sector0.txt                                                                                                
100% 3774     3.7KB/s   00:00
```

but when I try to copy the folder to my local machine, it fails:

```
root@b4860qds:~# scp -r administrator@10.6.120.80:/NMM/  ./
administrator@10.6.120.80's password:
scp: Failed to open file /NMM/.
```

Comment: Can you do `ssh administrator@10.6.120.80 ls -l /NMM/` for us? Maybe you have `x` but not `r` on the directory, which would prevent you from listing  all its contents (and hence knowing what to copy).

Comment: add words,   administrator@10.6.120.80  is my win7 PC, and it run the Freesshd software to start ssh sever. I have checked the the NMM folder security same with the file sector0.txt.  any other suggestion ? thx much for your answer.

Comment: Isn't NMM a symbolic link? 
Like said before, output of `ls -l` will help. Otherwise we can just guess.

Comment: Works for me on Linux (source and target), also on symlinks. Could be a Windows issue.

Comment: thx all, maybe about some SSH server configuration not well by myself. when I setup a Bitvise SSH  server . it work well.

Answer (score 0):

As you are copying from linux to windows drive, better you need to give the drive name like C,D,E.

(in below case where D refers to Drive, drive should prefix with double slash)

Example:

```
scp -r administrator@10.6.120.80://D:/NMM/  ./
```